# Replace whole string which contains substring per column in whole dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas: replacing values:

Currently the dataframe is:

| val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- |
| blue_ball | 4 |
| white ball | 1 |
| racket | 9 |
| red ball | 2 |
| Golf ba+ll | 1 |
| bow | 7 |
| chess | 3 |
| ball blue | 3 |

The desired output is:

| val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- |
| ball | 4 |
| ball | 1 |
| racket | 9 |
| ball | 2 |
| ball | 1 |
| bow | 7 |
| chess | 3 |
| ball | 3 |

I have tried:

```
df['val1'] = df['val1'].str.replace(df[df['val1'].str.contains("ball", na=False)],'ball')
```

I need to do this with each item in the store, additionally, some records are misspelled (ball blue) or contain symbols " _ + / * "

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misspelling is trickier but you can remove the special chars with `replace` and for the conditional operation you can use `numpy.where`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

texts = ["blue_ball", "white ball", "racket", "red ball", "Golf ba+ll", "bow", "chess", "ball blue"]
values = list(range(len(texts)))
df_dict = {"texts": texts, "values": values}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df["remove_special_chars"] = df.texts.replace('\+|_|\/|\*','', regex=True) # remove special chars
df["clean_texts"] = np.where(df["remove_special_chars"].str.contains("ball"), "ball", df["texts"])
```

Results
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, remove all non-letters and check for "ball"

```
m = (df['val1'].str.replace('[^a-z]', '', regex=True)
     .str.contains('ball', case=False)
     )

df.loc[m, 'val1'] = 'ball' 

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     val1  val2
0    ball     4
1    ball     1
2  racket     9
3    ball     2
4    ball     1
5     bow     7
6   chess     3
7    ball     3
```